# Why is menu displaying behind image?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, z-index

At this site: http://www.multiway.dk/
The dropdown menu is displaying behind the header image, which i dont quite understand as the menu has z-index: 100; and the image has z-index:1;

It works fine in FF, but in IE it doens't work??

Comment: i checked your menu it doesn't have a z-index. what class did you put it into? also did you set your position to absolute? could you provide us with a screenshot of what we should see? because the menu appears after the header in FF for me

Answer (score 0):

Yeh I had this a while back. I personally used:

http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/

plenty of fixes out there (:

Comment: Hmm, so do i put z-index: 3000; on my menu, and z-index:1000; on the menu container? Cant quite figure out how to use it? :S

Answer (score 0):

This is the famous Z-Index Bug

> For some reason, Internet Explorer
>   does some pretty funky things, and has
>   several known bugs with it’s rendering
>   engine that drive web developers like
>   me crazy.  While most of the known
>   bugs occur in relatively obscure
>   situations and go largely unnoticed,
>   there are a few that really stick out
>   and cause web developers to waste many
>   hours trying to fix them.  The way IE7
>   renders z-index stacking orders is one
>   of them.
>
> One way to fix many of the issues with
>   IE7 is to dynamically reverse the
>   default z-index stacking order of the
>   elements on your page. This will
>   ensure the elements higher in your
>   HTML source will also have a higher
>   z-index order on your page, solving
>   most of the IE stacking issues. If
>   you’re using jQuery (the best
>   Javascript library there is), here’s
>   the quick fix:

```
$(function() {
    var zIndexNumber = 1000;
    $('div').each(function() {
        $(this).css('zIndex', zIndexNumber);
        zIndexNumber -= 10;
    });
});
```

[Ref](http://www.vancelucas.com/blog/fixing-ie7-z-index-issues-with-jquery/)

---

Edit :
Move that jquery code to IE conditional comments.

```
<!--[if IE lte 7]>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$(function() {
    var zIndexNumber = 1000;
    $('div').each(function() {
        $(this).css('zIndex', zIndexNumber);
        zIndexNumber -= 10;
    });
});

$(".panel img").css("z-index","-1");
$(".menu_item").css("overflow","visble");


});

</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: I tried this, and if you look at the code now it contains the jQuery, but it still wont work ?

Comment: @Nicky : See if the edited code works. Remove it from the main code(its causing problem in other browsers) and put it in the IE conditional code.

Comment: I think it should be okay by default in IE8(assuming) try changing the conditional code to [if IE lte 7] (updated above) this will trigger the code only in IE lte (less than or equal to) 7. For the inner divs on the menu -- i've added $(".menu_item").css("overflow","visble"); to the IE comments, see if that helps.

Comment: Dont have IE8 :( - best of luck though